# pst-electricfield: How to use multido for placing multiple charges

Tags: pstricks, foreach, multido, pst-electricfield

So I tried to place multiple charges via the pst-electricfield package. Doing so manually works fine, but I'm trying to mimic a capacitor by placing many charges along a line. Is there a way to produce a foreach loop so I don't have to place each charge one by one? I've tried to use the multido command but with no success. (Unrecoverable error)

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-4,-4)(4,4)
        \psElectricfield[Q={\multido{\y=1+1}{3}{[1 0 \y]}},linecolor=red]
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

I'm thinking of a way to use a foreach loop in advance which produces all the charges and coordinates (e.g. [1 0 \y]). If I could store the output of all these expressions in a variable \Q, should I be able to use this in psElectricfield[Q={\Q}] ?
Does anyone know how I can store such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define `\Q`  outside of the macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}

\begin{document}
\def\q{[1 0 }
\def\Q{}
\multido{\iy=1+1}{3}{\xdef\Q{\Q\q \iy]}}

\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-4)(4,8)
\psElectricfield[Q=\Q,linecolor=red]
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]